# greatest common divisor in the ring $F(x)[y]$

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Assume $F$ is a field (we can assume here $F = \mathbb R$), and let $R = F(x)[y]$. If we now know that two elements $a,b$ in $R$ have no common divisor other than $1$ we can write $\gcd(a,b) = 1$. Is it in this particular ring still true (as it is in $\mathbb Z$) that we can write $1$ as a linear combination of $a$ and $b$? If yes, is there a way to find the coefficients?

I tried it with some simple examples and found for $a=x, b= y^2$  that.

$$(\frac 1 x + y^2) x + (-x)y^2 = 1$$

Further for $a=x+y, b=y^2$:

$$\frac 1 {x^2} (x-y)(x+y)+ \frac 1 {x^2} y^2 = 1$$

For another example $a = x+y^2,b=x^2+xy$ I was not able to come up with a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume the field $F$ is equal to $K$. Moreover that $K(x)$ is the field of rational functions in $x$. Then the answer to your question is "yes": the polynomial ring $L[y]$ in one variablle (here $y$) over a field $L$ is a principal ideal domain. In such a domain the greatest common divisor of two elements can be written as a linear combination of the two elements involved.

As for your example:

$
\frac{x-y}{x(x^2+x)}(x^2+xy)+\frac{1}{x^2+x}(x+y^2)=1
$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you explain how you were able to find these factors? Was it just guessing as I did or is there a method?

Comment: It was guessing - the elements are quite simple. There is however a method to find the factors: the (extended) Euklidean algorithm, which essentially consists of a sequence of polynomial divisions.